# Ruby - How to include classes in a Module

Tags: ruby

Im new in Ruby. I have seen that Modules in Ruby are used for namespacing or for mixin.

**I would like to use a module for namespacing. Module will include class definitions.**

This has been my attempt.

**lib/HtmlBody.rb**

```
module HtmlBody
    require_relative './html_body/HeadingTags'
    require_relative './html_body/AnchorTags'
    require_relative './html_body/ImgTags'
end
```

**lib/html_body/HeadingTags.rb**

```
class HeadingTags
  ...
end
```

And from another file, I would require the module *lib/HtmlBody*.

```
require_relative 'lib/HtmlBody'

HtmlBody::HeadingTags.new
```

This will return an error. :

```
1: from (irb):9:in `rescue in irb_binding'
NameError (uninitialized constant HtmlBody::HeadingTags)
```

Im not sure what the issue is. I understand that it says **uninitialized** but Im not sure why. It seems it is looking for a constant instead of reading the class?

How are you supposed to include classes located in separated files inside a module?

The is something that Im missing in Ruby and the **require/require_relative** probably.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't just define `HtmlBody::HeadingTags` in the ruby file?

Comment: If every class has 10 methods, putting them all in the same file will make the module to go into hundreds of lines. For readability, I would prefer to keep them in separate files.

Comment: You can define those inside of a separate file (class) and then use `extend` if they're class level methods, or `include` if they're instance methods. You can do what you're trying to do with `eval` but it's not recommended.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Im not sure what the issue is. I understand that it says **uninitialized** but Im not sure why. It seems it is looking for a constant instead of reading the class?

It is not clear to me what you mean by "reading the class". Yes, Ruby is looking for a constant. Variable names that begin with a capital letter are constants, ergo, `HtmlBody` is a constant, `HeadingTags` is a constant, and `HtmlBody::HeadingTags` is the constant `HeadingTags` located in a class or module that is referenced by the constant `HtmlBody`.

> How are you supposed to include classes located in separated files inside a module?

You namespace a class inside a module by defining the class inside the module. If you are *sure* that the module already exists, you can define the class like this:

```
class HtmlBody::HeadingTags
  # …
end
```

However, if `HtmlBody` is not defined (or is not a class or module), this will fail.

```
module HtmlBody
  class HeadingTags
    # …
  end
end
```

This will guarantee that module `HtmlBody` will be created if it doesn't exist (and simply re-opened if it already exists).

There is also a slight difference in constant lookup rules between the two, which is however not relevant to your question (but be aware of it).

> The is something that Im missing in Ruby and the **require/require_relative** probably.

Indeed, your question stems from a fundamental misunderstanding of what [`Kerne#load`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-load) / [`Kernel#require`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-require) / [`Kernel#require_relative`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-require_relative) does.

Here is the very complicated, detailed, in-depth explanation of all the incredibly convoluted stuff that those three methods do. Brace yourself! Are you ready? Here we go:

They run the file.

Wait … that's it? Yes, that's it! That's all there is to it. They run the file.

So, what happens when you run a file that looks like this:

> ```
> class HeadingTags
>   # …
> end
> ```

It defines a class named `HeadingTags` in the top-level namespace, right?

Okay, so what happens when we now do this:

> ```
> require_relative './html_body/HeadingTags'
> ```

Well, we said that `require_relative` simply runs the file. And we said that running that file defines a class named `HeadingTags` in the top-level namespace. Therefore, this will obviously define a class named `HeadingTags` in the top-level namespace.

Now, looking at your code: what happens, when we do this:

> ```
> module HtmlBody
>   require_relative './html_body/HeadingTags'
> end
> ```

Again, we said that `require_relative` simply runs the file. Nothing more. Nothing less. Just run the file. And what did we say running that file does? It defines a class named `HeadingTags` in the top-level namespace.

So, what will calling `require_relative` *from within the module definition of `HtmlBody`* do? It will define a class named `HeadingTags` *in the top-level namespace*. Because `require_relative` simply runs the file, and thus the result will be exactly the same as running the file, and the result of running file is that it defines the class in the top-level namespace.

So, how do you actually achieve what you are trying to do? Well, if you want to define a class inside a module, you have to … define the class inside the module!

**lib/html_body.rb**

```
require_relative 'html_body/heading_tags'
require_relative 'html_body/anchor_tags'
require_relative 'html_body/img_tags'

module HtmlBody; end
```

**lib/html_body/heading_tags.rb**

```
module HtmlBody
  class HeadingTags
    # …
  end
end
```

**lib/html_body/anchor_tags.rb**

```
module HtmlBody
  class AnchorTags
    # …
  end
end
```

**lib/html_body/img_tags.rb**

```
module HtmlBody
  class ImgTags
    # …
  end
end
```

**main.rb**

```
require_relative 'lib/html_body'

HtmlBody::HeadingTags.new
```

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the error `Uninitialized Constant` because, in ruby, `HeadingTags` and `HtmlBody::HeadingTags` are two different constants. Ruby does not take into consideration the file path here. To achieve what you want, you need to declare `HeadingTags` as belonging to `HtmlBody` explicitly, like this:

*htmlbody.rb*

```
module HtmlBody; end
```

*htmlbody/headingtags.rb*

```
module HtmlBody
    class HeadingTags; end
end
```

Or alternatively `class HtmlBody::HeadingTags; end`.
However, if you want to dynamically define constants under a module, you can look into the `const_set` method.

Answer (score 2):

Jorg's answer is much more thorough and goes through the why. I'll defer to his, but leave my succinct answer in place. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58034705/1937435

You can accomplish what you're trying to do with eval, but it's not recommended. The functionality you're looking for here is accomplished with include and extend.

`include` will assign a module's methods on the instance-level. `extend` will assign a module's methods on the class-level.

```
module HtmlBody; end

module HeadingInstanceMethods
  def h1
    puts "I am h1"
  end
end

module HeadingClassMethods
  def valid_headers
    ["h1", "h2"]
  end
end

module HtmlBody
  class HeadingTags
    include HeadingInstanceMethods
    extend HeadingClassMethods
  end
end 

HtmlBody::HeadingTags.valid_headers # => ["h1", "h2"]
HtmlBody::HeadingTags.new.h1 # => I am h1
```

When you splice these into separate files, just do the usual `require` or `require_relative` at the top of the file (not in the namespace) and call them accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, you gave me an answer for this. It looks weird! Not sure if Ruby provides modules to be used as Im trying to.

Comment: I am not downvoting this answer, but I *do* think it is not a very good answer for three reasons: 1) It is massively overcomplicated for what the OP is trying to accomplish. 2) It actually solves a different problem than the one the OP is trying to solve. 3) It does nothing to address the source of the OP's confusion; in fact, given the OP's comment under this answer, it rather looks like it *increases* the confusion.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I'll happily defer to yours over my hastily-written answer :)

Answer (score 0):

**I am not suggesting this is a good idea but ruby is always willing to give you enough rope to shoot yourself in the foot so...**

Just for fun you can hack this functionality together (with extremely generic assumptions made) as:

```
module HtmlBody
  def self.include_in_scope(constant_name,path)
    require_relative path
    self.const_set(constant_name.to_s, Object.send(:remove_const, constant_name.to_s))
  end
end

klass_list = {HeadingTags: './html_body/HeadingTags', 
              AnchorTags: './html_body/AnchorTags'
              ImgTags: './html_body/ImgTags'}

klass_list.each do |name,path|
   HtmlBody.include_in_scope(name, path) 
end
```

Now all the classes are namespaced under `HtmlBody` e.g. `HtmlBody::HeadingTags` but are not included in the top level scope e.g. `::HeadingTags` will raise a `NameError`.

[Example](https://repl.it/@engineersmnky/IncludeClassesInScope)